# How could I create this header effect but with an image behind it? HTML5

Tags: html, image, header

I'm looking to re-create this header but I want an image behind it instead of just a sold color, I want to use the black fade around but I can't find a way to get an image behind it.

[image]

```css
background:#1a1a2e;
border-left:1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

}
.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sidebar-nav li.sidebar-nav-item a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.1);
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}
#sidebar-wrapper.active {
  right: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: all .4s ease 0;
}
.masthead {
  min-height: 30rem;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 8rem;
  padding-bottom: 8rem;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%), url(https://www.nme.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Black-Widow-Avengers.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: inset 120px 100px 250px #000, inset -120px -100px 250px #000;
}
.masthead h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.masthead .mb-5 em {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.btn-xl {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #d35d6e;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1.25rem 2.5rem;
}
.btn-xl:hover {
  background-color: #fd3a69;
  color: #000;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.Container {
  margin: 2% 2% 0 3%;
}
.Movies img {
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0 #000;
  transition: .8s;
}
.Movies img:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
.Container h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  color: #f3e6e3;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #020314;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2% 15%;
}
.social-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
.social-icon:hover {
  color: #5F9EA0;
}
.footername {
  color: #FF7F50;
}
.footername:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #DC143C;
}
.scroll-to-top {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(52, 58, 64, 0.5);
  line-height: 45px;
  display: none;
}
.scroll-to-top:focus,
.scroll-to-top:hover {
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
.scroll-to-top i {
  font-weight: 800;
}
.menu-toggle:focus,
.menu-toggle:hover,
.sidebar-nav>.sidebar-brand a {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-toggle:hover,
.scroll-to-top:hover {
  background: #343a40;
}
@media min-width 992px {
  .masthead {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .masthead h1 {
    font-size: 5.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead d-flex">
  <div class="container text-center my-auto">
    <h1 class="mb-1">Welcome</h1>
    <h3 class="mb-5"><em>Join our discord Community</em></h3><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger" href="https://discord.gg/YmtGhGQPSu">Join Now</a>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: @mplungjan Here's a link to the CSS used https://pastebin.com/qPMRtHe3.

Comment: @mplungjan I think I added the CSS code!

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry I'm new to this website, added it back!

Comment: Your CSS is incomplete. Please click edit, scroll down, click "edit above snippet" and complete the CSS in the CSS panel. I added a Black Widow image for you

Answer (score -1):

try this

header {
background-image: url("")
}